# Opening downloaded excel sheet with openpyx, works only after saving it myself again

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to open an excel sheet with Python, but I get a huge error when trying to open a downloaded sheet.

However, when I open the sheet in excel and save it as a copy - it works fine with this file. I believe it has got something to do with the security setting (file downloaded from the internet, may be blocked to protect computer etc).

How do I solve this issue? This is my python program:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C://users//userme/Downloads/file.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
print (sheet.cell(row=15, column=2).value)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\userme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 57, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.date)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/userme/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/xlsimp.py", line 5, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C://users//userme/Downloads/Daily_20181002_TTT.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\userme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 211, in load_workbook
    wb.properties = DocumentProperties.from_tree(src)
  File "C:\Users\userme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 100, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "C:\Users\userme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\core.py", line 110, in __init__
    self.modified = modified
  File "C:\Users\userme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 270, in __set__
    super(DateTime, self).__set__(instance, value)
  File "C:\Users\userme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\nested.py", line 36, in __set__
    super(Nested, self).__set__(instance, value)
  File "C:\Users\userme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 69, in __set__
    value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
  File "C:\Users\userme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 59, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: Which openpyxl Version? The `xlsx` is probably broken.

Comment: Submit a bug report with a sample file. Can't do much without the file.

Comment: I can't attach the sample file, because when I save it - the problem is solved. And the file contains to much sensitive information.

Comment: Just a follow up on this one, it appeared the excel sheet contained very annoying comments like this: <!-- saslongversion 56725672.22.2-->  : which crashed openpyxl.